# Code working on localhost, but not working when deployed using Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I wrote a code for validating a form. It works perfectly on my local host. However when I deploy it on the internet, I get an error. Here is the entire code and the error associated with it:

```
import webapp2
from calendar import *
import cgi

form = """
<form method = "post">
<label>Month<input type = "text" name = "mon" value = "%(month)s"></label>
<label>Day<input type = "text" name = "dy" value = "%(day)s"></label>
<label>Year<input type = "text" name = "yr" value = "%(year)s"></label>
<div style="color:red">%(error)s</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type = "submit">
</form>
"""

def escape_html(s):
    return cgi.escape(s, quote = True)
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    error = ""
    def write_form(self, error, month, day, year):
        self.response.write(form %{"error":error, "month":escape_html(month), "day":escape_html(day), "year":escape_html(year)})
    def get(self):
    #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.write_form("", "", "", "")
    def post(self):
        mon = valid_month(self.request.get("mon"))  
        dy = valid_day(self.request.get("dy"))  
        yr = valid_year(self.request.get("yr"))
        month = self.request.get("mon")
        day = self.request.get("dy")
        year = self.request.get("yr")
        if not(mon and dy and yr):
            self.write_form("Please refill the form with correct data!", month, day, year)
        else:
            self.redirect("/thanks")

class ThanksHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("Thanks for submitting your data!") 

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), ('/thanks', ThanksHandler)],    debug=True)
```

calendar.py

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

def valid_month(month):
    temp = month.capitalize()
    for e in months:
        if e == temp:
            return e
    return None     

def valid_day(day):
    try:
        num = int(day)
    except:
        return None
    if num<=31 and num>0:
        return num
    else:
        return None

def valid_year(year):
    if year and year.isdigit():
        num = int(year)
        if num>1900 and num<2020:
            return num
```

This is the error that I get after uploading on the internet:

Internal Server Error

The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~deploymentapp/1.370308128873516940/main.py", line 27, in post
    mon = valid_month(self.request.get("mon"))
NameError: global name 'valid_month' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me with this? I am stuck on this for 3 days now. No matter what I try to do with my code, I still couldn't make it run on the internet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your main does not import correctly calendar.valid_month(). Check the filepaths and try "from calendar import valid_month" instead of importing everything in order to locate the error.

Comment: I get a 500 error when I use the following for importing my calendar file: from calendar import valid_month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not familiar with GAE but it will probably be to do with the order in which packages are being imported.

Try changing

```
from calendar import *
```

to

```
from .calendar import *
```

In the first case it might be importing the system calendar package. In the second case you're asking it to import the local package (your calendar.py).

Comment: i'm not sure but I think there is a difference between Python2.xx and 3.xx : in Python3 you are forced to separate system and local packages includes, whereas in 2.xx you can keep the ambiguity(the interpretor will resolve automatically). Maybe that's why there was a difference between localhost and GoogleEngineHost

Comment: I changed calendar.py to calendar1.py and its working now! I must be importing the built-in calendar module in python! Thanks a ton for pointing this out to me!

Comment: You don't need to change the name of the module. Just put the dot in front of it when importing.

Comment: Oh, weird. I'm sure Google have a good reason for that (annoying behaviour).